# How can I store a >1MB value via memcached?

Tags: python, linux, django, caching, memcached

At the beginning, I installed `memcached 1.4.1`, using the parameter `-I 2m`, but it did not work. Then I installed `memcached 1.4.25`, and `-I 2m` still is not working either. In django, `cache.set(key,value)` when the value size is more than 1 MB, it returns `None`, and no value is stored in cache.

According to some article, I can store the big value into multi keys, each value less than 1MB, it works. But key management is problematic.

Then I modified the source code `memcached.c`:

```
settings.item_size_max = 1024 * 1024; /* The famous 1MB
```

to reflect:

```
settings.item_size_max = 5 * 1024 * 1024; /* The famous 1MB
```

and after recompiling, it failed again. It still does not store values larger than 1M.

How can I successfully store a >1MB key via `memcached`?

Versions:

```
CentOS 7, python 2.7.5, django 1.7
```

> The default maximum object size is 1MB. In memcached 1.4.2 and later,
>   you can change the maximum size of an object using the -I command line
>   option. For versions before this, to increase this size, you have to
>   re-compile memcached. You can modify the value of the POWER_BLOCK
>   within the slabs.c file within the source. In memcached 1.4.2 and
>   higher, you can configure the maximum supported object size by using
>   the -I command-line option. For example, to increase the maximum
>   object size to 5MB:
>
> ```
> $ memcached -I 5m
> ```
>
> If an object is larger than the maximum object size, you must manually
>   split it. memcachedis very simple: you give it a key and some data, it
>   tries to cache it in RAM. If you try to store more than the default
>   maximum size, the value is just truncated for speed reasons.

Comment: did you restart it after recompiling? if not, you're still running the OLD version...

Comment: sure ! If I install with yum , I use systemctl . If I install by compile , I kill the process and rerun the memcached.